# DataGrid binding column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Is it possible to force update second datagrid column when we change data in first column without using INotifyPropertyChanged, only in XAML? I want update penalty property when is changed date in datepicker.

```
   <DataGrid x:Name="orderBooksDg" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="23,234,24,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Height="119" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Book.Name}" Header="Nazwa książki" IsReadOnly="True" Width="350"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Data zwrotu" IsReadOnly="False" Width="150">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker x:Name="date" SelectedDate="{Binding ReturnDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="penalty" Binding="{Binding Penalty, StringFormat=N2}" Header="Kara"  Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should first use

> DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate

not

> DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate

to edit value in DataGrid Column